# Regex for matching character or line anchor

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match entries in delimited files that have been enclosed in text qualifiers. If X is the field delimiter, Y is the qualifier, and a is the entry, expected forms of the input strings include:

```
XYaaaYXYaaaYXYaaaYX
YaaaYXYaaaYXYaaaYX
XYaaaYXYaaaYXYaaaY
YaaaYXYaaaYXYaaaY
```

I.e. there may or may not be field delimiters on the beginnings and ends of the lines.

Ultimately, I'm trying to pull out YaaaY but *only* if bordered by either a delimiter or a line beginning/end. For example, the regex should match on XYaaaYX and YaaaYX but not on XYaaaYaaaYX. Fairly easy except that I can't figure out the appropriate "or" condition for the line ends.

This is trivial for matching the delimiter-bordered case (regex =  `XYa*YX`), but I can't  figure out how to do X OR beginning-of-line. Things like `[^|X]Ya*Y[X|$]` seem close but don't work because the brackets mess up the line anchors.

Have searched every discussion I can find - nothing I've found can answer this. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: If you want a good resource for learning regex, my favorite is [Regular-Expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using groupings rather than character classes, eg.

```
/(^|X)Ya*Y(X|$)/
```

Comment: Awesome. Knew is must be something simple. Thanks!